# install4j - jre.bundle is not updated

Tags: java, macos, install4j

I'm using install4j 5.1.15 and I have installer for Mac OS and Windows 64-bit with bundled JRE 7. Installation/Update of my app works without problems with this installer.

Now I need to upgrade bundled JRE (installed inside `/Applications/MyApp/.install4j/jre.bundle`) from 7 to 8. I built new installer with JRE 8 (and with checked option `Update bundled JRE` in the configuration of my update action).

**Problem:** JRE 8 is installed when I do a clean installation, but when I'm trying to update existing installation then existing JRE 7 is not updated to JRE 8. Other files are updated correctly. The same behaviour is on Mac OS and also Windows 64-bit. Also I don't see any warnings/errors in a log file. It is a bug or I missed something?

**EDIT**: There is no message about updating JRE files in `installation.log`, even when `updateBundledJre: true`:

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.InstallFilesAction [ID 767]: Execute action
       Property sizeCalculatorScript: null
       Property installRuntime: false
       Property saveDownloadedFiles: false
       Property updateBundledJre: true
       Property checkFreeSpace: true
       Property validateApplicationId: false
       Property delay: false
       Property triggerReboot: true
       Property directoryResolverScript: null
       Property fileFilterScript: null
       Property showFileNames: true
       Property rollbackSupported: true
Install file: /Applications/MyApp/my-file.tmp; size: 245 bytes; exists: true
Execute action successful after 5650 ms
```

Comment: You can look at the file .install4j/installation.log to see if it tries to install the JRE 8 files

Comment: Thank you Ingo for your comment. I attached installation.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to change value of `installRuntime` property to `true` and it resolved my problem. During update process current JRE is moved to folder `/Applications/MyApp/.install4j/__i4j_jre_backup` and new JRE is installed correctly. It works for Mac OS and also Windows now.

`installation.log`:

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.InstallFilesAction [ID 767]: Execute action
       Property sizeCalculatorScript: null
       Property installRuntime: true
       Property saveDownloadedFiles: false
       Property updateBundledJre: true
       Property checkFreeSpace: true
       Property validateApplicationId: false
       Property delay: false
       Property triggerReboot: true
       Property directoryResolverScript: null
       Property fileFilterScript: null
       Property showFileNames: true
       Property rollbackSupported: true
       Install file: 
Install file: /Applications/MyApp/my-file.tmp; size: 245 bytes; exists: true
Install file: /Applications/MyApp/.install4j/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java; size: 103632 bytes; exists: false
       File options set to: [fileTime: Wed Jul 29 12:34:46 CEST 2015, mode: 644, overwriteMode: Always ask except for update, shared: false, uninstallMode: If created, but not for update, delayIfNecessary: false]
...
Execute action successful after 12345 ms
```